# Changed email, can't sign in on PS4

Tags: ps4, psn

Since I changed email provider, I changed every account I had to use my new email. So far so good, no problem.
But now, I turned on my PS4, and it say I m not signed in. Not a big deal, just need to input the right email.

But going to Sign In just put me on a loading screen. Going to Options>PSN/Account Management only show Sign In, all other options are greyed out.

How can I change the email now? The only option I see is changing it back to the original one from the browser, and changing it back from the PS4, if that is even possible.

TL:DR: PS4 have saved a old email, and try to sign in with it. How to change that email?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up resetting the email to the old one from the browser so I could sign in on the PS4, then sign out, resetting the email on the new one, and signing in with it.

I ll accept any answer that propose a alternative.